# Webapp slowing down page load (Business Catalyst

Tags: business-catalyst

Hi Business Catalyst folks,

I have a problem with a web app that is supposed to output 44 lists items. I find that the page loads very slow, for no reason. This has been an issue for a year, as I have been unable to solve. I have stripped the page of all css and javascript to see if it is the issue and I still have the problem:

[Page in Question](https://test-onlove.worldsecuresystems.com/momma.html)

Can someone shed some light as to why this is happening?

Comment: Can you please provide the template that you are using to render the web apps? 
Are you using Liquid to render them, or just the BC module?
Please give some more info, looking at your HTML there is nothing wrong with it

Comment: Yes, the link to the page is a good start, but providing the raw HTML would be even better.